# AdminConfig.showAttribute from Java Code

Tags: java, command, websphere, wsadmin

I want to run the following wsadmin command from my java code.

```
AdminConfig.showAttribute('lp1(cells/iap/nodes/iapnode/servers/server1/server.xml#ListenerPort_1447149354628)', 'stateManagement')
```

I saw that there is a CommandMgr with AdminCommands, where I can set some parameters.

But I can't get out, which Command is the right one.

Can someone give me a code example, how to write the wsadmin command menitoned above in java-code?

Comment: you should be able to use JMX to access MBeans and invoke any wsadmin command using MBeans.  See this thread: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014440034

Comment: Thats right. I can access MBean attributes/operations via the AdminService. But the MBean doesn't contain the attribute I am searching for (it is "initialState"). But via the wsadmin console I am able to get the attribute.